# Filling a SWING JTREE with Data from a mysql database via jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jtree

I am having some trouble grasping how to fill a SWING JTREE with data from my database. Say my data look as such:

```
id | parent_fk | folder |   

 1 |   NULL     |   Customer    
 2 |   NULL     |   Accounts  
 3 |   NULL     |   Templates  
 4 |   1        |   TestCustomer  
 6 |   4        |   TestAlbum1  
 8 |   4         |   TestAlbum2
```

And what I am planning to do is fill a JFrame JTree (say info_tree) with the root being root, having a child "TestCustomer" and this child having 2 children being "TestAlbum1" and "TestAlbum2"

What I have done sofar is:

- Execute a query that returns the above
- Make ArrayLists for id, parent and folder
- Make a DefaultMutableTreeNode for the root called "Root"
- Make a DefaultMutableTreeNode for the id to hold the "TestCustomer"

Now I seem to get stuck as far as how to loop to get children to link to the correct parent through parent_fk

```
public void TreeExample() { 
  Connection conn = null;
    try {
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="connection">
        String CS = "******";
        String user = "*****";
        String password = "*****";
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(CS, user, password);
        String prepSqlStatement = "Select * FROM ag_album";

        PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(prepSqlStatement);
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();

        ArrayList id = new ArrayList();
        List folder = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList parent_fk = new ArrayList();

        //          create the root node
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");

        DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);

        while (rs.next()) {
            id.add(rs.getString("id"));
            parent_fk.add(rs.getString("parent_fk"));
            folder.add(rs.getString("folder"));
        }

        int i = 0;
        for (Object r : id) {
            //        create the child nodes
            DefaultMutableTreeNode idNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(folder.get(i));
            root.add(idNode);
            i++;
                            }
 info_tree.setModel(treeModel);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.getLogger(BrandITFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}
```

I have tried a foreach loop that looked at the objects in parent_pk, but that resulted in the tree not showing up. For example:

```
                int j = 0;
            for (Object f : parent_fk) {
                idNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(folder.get(j)));
                j++;
            }
```

I seem to be stuck on the logic to find out how to get items from my resultSet to add them as a child to a parent who is also from the same resultSet.

If anybody can help, thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).  Hard code some data to replace the DB.

Comment: Are id, parent_fk and folder supposed to be in a class? You are mixing your DB logic with UI logic which makes it difficult to see where exactly the problem is.